# Telnet Server in C# :AsyncConnection in C#

Tags: c#, network-programming

I am writing a telnet server When i Execute the following program my program is exiting 
  and it is displaying content in only 1 cmd.I have used TCP ASynchronously my content 
  is not displaying on 2cmd .Please help me regarding this issue.

```
public void Start()
{
    Int32 port = 21;
    IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
    server.Start();
    Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
    Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
    StartAccept();
}

private void StartAccept()
{
    // listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(OnAccept, listener);

    server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(HandleAsyncConnection, server);
}

private void HandleAsyncConnection(IAsyncResult res)
{ 
    String data = null;
    TcpListener listener = (TcpListener)res.AsyncState;

     //listen for new connections again
     TcpClient client = server.EndAcceptTcpClient(res);
     Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
     while (true)
     { 
        server.Start();
        // TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
        data = null;
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        int b, i, a;
        string str = null;
        string str1 = null;
        string str3 = null;
        int k = 0;
        int c = 0;
        if (stream.CanWrite)
        {
            if (c == 0)
            {
                `enter code here`
                byte[] Mybuff = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Please Enter USer ID and Password");
                stream.Write(Mybuff, 0, Mybuff.Length);
                //StartAccept();
                c++;
            }
            else 
            {
                byte[] Mybuff = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Please Enter USer ID and Password");
                stream.Write(Mybuff, 0, Mybuff.Length);
                StartAccept();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do both command prompts utilise the same TCP code?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a `Console.ReadLine();` after `StartAccept();` to keep the console running.

Comment: Thank u so much for the reply. I was desparately waiting for it!!
Contents are not displaying in 2 cmd how to do it?

Comment: @IITmadras please clarify the question, may be extending the original one?

Comment: yaa i am implmenting a telnet server when i execute the program i am connecting to 2 command prompts by commands telent 127.0.0.1 21 . now i am displaying content on Cmd by using byte[] Mybuff = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Please Enter USer ID and Password") but it is displaying content on only 1 cmd i want this on both cmd prompts

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to get what you type into console 1 to appear in console 2. Or at least to get the same data to appear in both console windows as sent by telnet commands from another console window.

If this is the case and you're using the same code to setup your command consoles then this won't work locally due to port clashes. The first command console doesn't reliquish ownership of port 21 for the second console to use.

On a windows machine it is now possible to implement port sharing using some WCF functionality. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395195.aspx) for more information.

It is normally advisable to use port numbers that aren't close to any other program when writing your own application. Say 17657 instead of 21, but this may be coloured by what your application intends to do.